# Why doesn't my drupal 8 bootstrap subtheme show search results?

Tags: theming, 8

I have a bootstrap subtheme I'm using for the following site - kobejet.com.

Everything looks and has been working correctly, up until about 2 weeks ago, when the search results started showing only number, with no actual results.

It seems the results are being returned, as the numbering is correct for how many results there *should* be for any inquiry. For example, if you search for "computer" - there should be about 14 results, but only the numbering shows.

I've tried to go over my installation, comparing my child/subtheme to the base theme and CDN starter kit, but have yet to make any headway.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the same issue. When i switch to Bootstap as default main-theme, i can see the sam issue. When i switch to batik, it works fine.

Comment: Sorry Sebastien just saw this - it was so long ago I don't remember what I did that fixed it or how it fixed itself. I don't know if it helps but you can see it properly functioning on kobejet.com with the bootstrap theme if inspecting that might help.